# is it okay to declare an array like this: `int arr[3/0]` in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want this array to have a capacity that's big enough And the compiler is okay with the declaration `int arr[3/0]`.

I'm not saying it's exactly infinite. I'm saying it won't tell you to stop inputting elements into the array as long as there's no stack overflow or things like that.
I wonder if it's not recommended.

## UPDATE:

So I guess some guys got me wrong.
I know the dynamic container which I'm using like this:

```
int *elements;
cin>>numberOfElements;
elements = new int[numberOfElements];
free(elements);
```

I'm just wondering if `int elements[3/0]` would do this trick to replace the code above.

Comment: "like, inifinite capacity"? What's that like?

Comment: You cannot declare a variable of infinite capacity, as your computer is most definitely not infinite. It might be better to explain what you actually want.

Comment: Do you have a computer with infinite capacity?

Comment: You can use any constant expression, but division by zero is never a good idea.

Comment: How the hell did your compiler accept this ?
But even if it compiles, it's a guaranteed stackoverflow or crash.
You want to store something like 100 TB of memory ? Go buy a supercomputer. You want to store many items, but don't know if it will be 5, 136 or 1500 ? Use a vector

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks.

Comment: And by infinite I'm not saying it's exactly infinite. I'm saying it won't tell you to stop inputting elements into the array, under most circumstances. @John

Comment: @Allen Provide an example of the code you want to work.

Comment: Oh and just so you know, division by zero is not automatically "infinite", it's just plain mathematically impossible.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So writing like this may get error in some other IDEs or compilers? I'm using Clion fyi.

Comment: Why have people piled on the downvotes? Seems like a fair question to me.

Comment: Got so many down votes today. Reputation went from 46 to 23. :( lol.

Comment: "unclear what you're asking" LOL you people could just learn to read then maybe you'd understand better

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for standing by me. But indeed I really need to improve myself and therefore don't ask stupid questions and waste others' time. I feel so sorry about this.

Comment: Don't let them bully you into submission. Hold your head up high. And upvote my answer lol

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Kind of got banned to ask questions :-(. Gotta get a new account.

Comment: @Allen: Ban evasion won't work out too well for you... especially not now that you've publicly admitted to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C (or C++) are blocks of memory. The compiler needs to know how big the array is in order to allocate the needed amount of memory. They are not expandable. To make an array bigger, you have to allocate a new array with more memory, and copy the old array into it.

There are solutions to this though. If you need something that can allocate additional memory as more items are added, then you'll need to use a class such as the container class "vector".

For more info, search on "C++ Containers".

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm using the container and all I wanna ask is that if int arr[3/0] would be ok since my compiler doesn't meet errors.

Comment: "3/0" would ask the compiler to divide 3 by 0. I'm surprised that the compiler didn't complain about it. I think the specific answer is "No", you can't define an array using arr[3/0];

Comment: Thanks for the kind and specific answer! I found it really helpful.

Comment: Oh and FYI, the IDEs I use don't report errors on division by 0 and if I try to cout it it would cout as inf, short for infinite.

Comment: Ha! Interesting to know. I'm showing my age, but "divide by zero" has been the bane of programmers for decades :-) Computers typically consider division by zero to result in either an exception, or a NAN (not a number).

Comment: @RonLisle: No, you'd get inf not NaN; I don't have my copy of ISO/IEC 60559:2011 on me, but see IEEE-754 §7.2. Though that does depend on the operands being floating-point (which they're not here) - integer division by zero is likely to result in a floating-point exception (ironically) on common CPUs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If `3/0` is used as the size of an array, it is a constant expression, and (if it was evaluated) would be evaluated at compile time. Since it is undefined behaviour, it will probably never be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by zero is logically an error, one which is diagnosed in different ways depending on how you attempt to do it:

- For floating-point operands, floating-point division by zero occurs and this is defined by IEEE-754 §7.2 to result in an "infinity" value;
- For integer operands, division by zero (ironically) results in a "floating-point exception" or `SIGFPE` on modern processors;
- For compile-time constants, like you have here, it's possible that your compiler is "performing" the calculation at compile-time and baking floating-point "infinity" into the program even though the operands are integers; I can't seem to get my compiler to do this, but it would be allowed to because the division by zero is considered to have *undefined behaviour* by the language standard.

Regardless, using "infinity" as an array dimension is not possible. Arrays in C++ must have known, fixed, integer bounds.

However, you can use a `std::vector`, an auto-resizing "array" that expands automatically as you add things to it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're better off using a dynamic container (such as `std::vector`). Then you don't have to specify the limits that it will grow to, which I think might be what you're really interested in

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm using the container and all I wanna ask is that if `int arr[3/0]` would be ok since my compiler doesn't meet errors.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're most likely looking for what's called in C++, [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). It's used like this:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> elements; // you can optionally reserve space for n elements in memory
    elements.push_back(123);
    // elements' destructor is automatically called, no free/delete necessary
}
```

An array is not a dynamic container.